# At least one vertex of a tetrahedron projects to the interior of the opposite triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

How i can give a fast proof of the following fact:
Given four points on $\mathbb{R}^3$ not contained in a plane we can choose one such that its projection to the plane passing through the others is in the triangle generated by the three others points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define projection?  Orthogonal or oblique projection?

Comment: Orthogonal projection

Comment: You can develop a counter example by construction.  Consider four co-planar points arranged in a square. The perturb one of them by a displacement of dz in a direction orthogonal to the plane.  Clearly , its projection takes it back to the original square which is not in the triangle defined by the other three points.

Comment: @Tpofofn That doesn't provide a counter example.  There are three other points (and therefore three other triangles) that we need to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false.

Just like anyone else, start from 4 points on the plane $z = 0$ which forms a square . For example, $(1,0,0)$,$(0,1,0)$,$(-1,0,0)$ and $(0,-1,0)$. Perturb them by a small amount in the $z$-direction to form a tetrahedron. More precisely, pick some small $\eta > 0$ and consider the tetrahedron formed by following 4 vertices

$$A(1,0,\eta),\quad B(0,1,-\eta),\quad C(-1,0,\eta),\quad D(0,-1,-\eta)$$

It is easy to see this tetrahedron is [isohedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isohedral_figure). The faces are not merely congruent, they are transitive. For any faces $F_1$ and $F_2$, there is a symmetry of the tetrahedron which maps the face $F_1$ into $F_2$.

For this tetrahedron, if the statement works for one vertex, then it will work for all vertices. Let's look at the vertex $D$ with respect to the face $ABC$. In order for $D$ to project into some point inside $ABC$ (either interior or boundary), a necessary condition
is the outward pointing normals for the faces $ABC$ and $CDA$ is making an angle $\ge 90^\circ$.

By direct computation, the outward pointing normals for the faces $ABC$ and $CDA$ are 
$$
\begin{cases}
\hat{n}_{ABC} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4\eta^2}}(0,2\eta,1)\\
\hat{n}_{CDA} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4\eta^2}}(0,-2\eta,1)
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad \hat{n}_{ABC}\cdot\hat{n}_{CDA} = \frac{1 - 4\eta^2}{1 + 4\eta^2}
$$
When $|\eta| < \frac12$, we find $\hat{n}_{ABC}\cdot\hat{n}_{CDA} > 0$. This means the two normal vectors is making an angle less than $90^\circ$. As a result, the projection of $D$ onto the plane containing $ABC$ doesn't fall inside $ABC$ (either interior or boundary). Since the tetrahedron is isohedral, same thing happens to other three vertex/face combinations.

Comment: [+1] Excellent. A side remark : A geometrical reasoning would lead to the equivalent formula for the angle $\alpha$ between the two normals : $2\eta=\tan \tfrac{\alpha}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the four points are the vertices of a square?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i forgot to say "not contained in a plane".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graphical supplement (that I cannot place into a comment) to the excellent answer by @achille hui .

I have taken the case $\eta=0.4.$ with normals in red.

The (complicated) name of this polyhedron is "tetragonal disphenoid" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disphenoid).

[image]